# microsoft office outlook 12.0 AUTH DIGEST-MD5 disable

Tags: windows, email, authentication, outlook-2007

How can i disable AUTH method DIGEST-MD5 in Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0. I want MOO 12.0 to only authenticate users using method LOGIN.